# UITapGestureRecognizer Recognize taps on main view (not inputs or buttons)

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I would like to get notified when a user clicks any part of the background of my UIView; basically if the user clicks outside of any control that is on my UIView (tables, textfields, buttons, etc).

How do I go about it? I tried doing this:

```
if ([touch.view isKindOf:[UIView class]]) {
    do something....
}
```

But, obviously all controls extend UIView... so, I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following:

```
backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHit:)] autorelease];
[backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

-(void) tapHit:(UITapGestureRecognizer *tap) {
  NSLog( @"background tapped" );
}
```

Comment: I´ve tried that on a tabeView but it seems that the tableView interaction covers the backgroundView interaction. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is add a separate background view that is a child of your VC's main view. You can simply make it transparent so it doesn't interfere with your styling. Place is in the behind all the other children views. Then register your GR on that view.